# Food delivery app : bloc or Provider which one to use?

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I am a beginner in Flutter. I want to make a Food delivery app, I have seen many state management types such as Provider, bloc, getx, and redux. Actually, I am so confused, which one to use. I think there are more confused like this. I have read provider is google recommended but still, they use bloc. So I have started learning but I have seen many complex apps uses bloc. So is there anyone please suggest to me, which one I want to use?

Comment: well you have also a confusion in there, there use provider with BLoC the patter no, Felix Angelov flutter_bloc state management. I will recommend you try first Provider you will find lots of documentations and videos around that will teach you how to use it. You will have an opportunity to use the other or you could create a small example repo and try a coupe different state management to lear about them.   Welcome to the Dart Side.

Comment: So you are saying that use provider for Food delivery app. provider is better than bloc?

Comment: I would recommend mobx, I am using it in 2 apps in the company where I work. Easy to understand, works very well and is fully testable. https://pub.dev/packages/mobx

Comment: have you used provider or bloc? @Luiz

Comment: I saw some talks about bloc, it only makes sense if you intend to use the angular dart, and never get to see anything about the provider.

Comment: still, confused again... then why did google recommend it? will check later about mobx.

Comment: so what did you use @TS?

Answer (score 4):

I have used bloc (with rxdart), mobx, provider to varying degrees.
First of all, the provider is officially recommended. There is nothing wrong with using it. I have used the provider myself.
I recently learned about getx. I looked at the documentation and found that the functions are very rich and not redundant. It can be independent. I think it can be tried and used. If you don’t have a favorite, you can take a look at getx. It will let you Development is more convenient